# Sending Large data from View to Controller in MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I am getting table records, I need to send it to Controller so that I can send email. When I tried with following code, it's throwing error

```
  var emailList = '';
  $('.checkBoxClass').each(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {

        emailList += $(this).val() + ',';
    }
});

body = 'Hi Team'
console.log('emIl ' + emailList);
var baseUrl = ".";
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: baseUrl + "/Dashboard/GetFinanceSendMail",
    data:  "{'emailList': '" + JSON.stringify(emailList) +  "', body' : '" + body + "' }",
    success: function (json) {
        alert(json);
    }
});
```

> Error as : HTTP Error 404.15 - Not Found The request filtering module
> is configured to deny a request where the query string is too long.
>
> Most likely causes: Request filtering is configured on the Web server
> to deny the request because the query string is too long.

I have tried to add following code, still same error

```
var formData = new FormData();
var objArr = [];

objArr.push({ "emIl": emailList, });

//JSON obj
formData.append('objArr', JSON.stringify(objArr))


body = 'Hi Team'
console.log('emIl ' + emailList);
var baseUrl = ".";
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: baseUrl + "/Dashboard/GetFinanceSendMail",
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    data: formData,
```

Here is Controller Code

```
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetFinanceSendMail(string emailList, string body)
    {
        List<string> emails = emailList.Split(',').ToList();
        // Send Email add optiona arg to the method
        _openPobl.TriggerFinanceEmail(body, emails);
        return Json(emails, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: So if the query string is too long, why not send it in the body of the HTTP request instead? You tried that and it's giving you an error? What error?

Comment: You need to set the Content-Type header of the request to match how you are passing the data. It should match how you have the action set up in your MVC code. You cannot just change the JavaScript without changing the receiving action.

Comment: Error as : HTTP Error 404.15 - Not Found The request filtering module is configured to deny a request where the query string is too long.

Most likely causes: Request filtering is configured on the Web server to deny the request because the query string is too long.

Comment: Controller code also added to main post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fix the action, remove [get]

```
 
 Route[("~/Dashboard/GetFinanceSendMail")]
    public JsonResult GetFinanceSendMail(string emailList, string body)
```

and ajax

```
var emailList = '';
  $('.checkBoxClass').each(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {

        emailList += $(this).val() + ',';
    }
});

var body = 'Hi Team';

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:  "/Dashboard/GetFinanceSendMail",
    data:  {emailList: emailList, body :  body  },
    success: function (json) {
        alert(json);
    }
});
```

but if you want to use post much more reliable to create a viewmodel class

```
public class ViewModel
{
public string EmailList {get;set;}
public string Body {get;set;}
}
```

action

```
   Route[("~/Dashboard/GetFinanceSendMail")]
   public JsonResult GetFinanceSendMail(ViewModel model)
.....
```

and ajax

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:  "/Dashboard/GetFinanceSendMail",
    data:  { model: {emailList: emailList, body :  body } },
    success: function (json) {
        alert(json);
    }
});
```